# регулярное выражения для разделения строки по символу

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

нужно регулярное выражение которое "обрезает" строку вида `en_1231313.png, en_37458389.png`.. что бы вышло `1231313.png, 37458389.png`
Получилось только для имен файлов, добраться до `_` никак не получается. Или проще с каким-нибудь `explode()` это сделать?

```
([^\s]+(?=\.(jpg|gif|png))\.\2)
```

Comment: что за язык? судя по _explode_ - это php?

Comment: да php.Пардоньте, забыл указать в описании

Comment: `[^_]+_`  вот таким начало обрежьте

Comment: то есть вы просто хотите сделать `replace('en_', '')` для строки?

Comment: да, мне нужно всё что идёт после `_`. Но перед `_` может быть не только `en`

Comment: тогда я не совсем понимаю, что мешает сделать этот replace

Comment: Поиск "_" в строке и через substr выделяем все что после него. Regexp не нужен, дарагой!

Comment: спасибо, дарагой) совсем забыл про substr

Comment: `list($prefix, $filename) = explode("_", $source)`

Comment: @dirk вы не забыли про explode - это гораздо лучше :)

Answer (score 1):

Если настаиваете на регулярных выражениях, вот подходящее:

```
.+_([^.]+\.[^.]+)$
```

Пример работы (зеленым выделено захватываемое совпадение):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Можно обойтись без регулярных выражений.

```
substr($string, strrpos($string, '_') + 1)
```

[Рабочий пример на Ideone](http://ideone.com/0leIkL):

```
$test = [
  'asda_en_37458389.png',
  'en_12312321.png'
];

foreach ($test as $test_case) {
  echo substr($test_case, strrpos($test_case, '_') + 1) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

> 37458389.png
>   12312321.png